# 5 minutely temperature graph 1 day?

Tags: word-choice

I have a graph that shows data at 5-minute intervals for 1 day. I am trying to come up with a title for this graph.

I am thinking of something like: "5 minutely temperature graph 1 day"

However, it just sounds wrong.

What is a better title for my graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temperature at 5 minute intervals over 1 day

Comment: I like this one, its clear and concise! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) . Mark it as the answer if it's the one you go with.

Comment: I will, you answered too quick I have to wait :P

Comment: I would put a hyphen between *5* and *minute* to avoid the confusion with *minute intervals, five of them.*

Answer (score 0):

A good way to name it would be

> One Day 5-minute-interval Temperature Graph

OR

> One Day 5 Minute Interval Temperature Graph

If it's going to depict this **everyday** then

> Daily 5-minute-interval Temperature Graph

Comment: I disagree that this is a good way. It is grammatical but barely readable, even with hyphens. Also, I would put a hyphen between *one* and *day* and not capitalise *day.*

Comment: The capitalization was on account of it being a title. We often capitalize important words in a title. As a heading or title, this is the sort we prefer in academic or technical circles. "Temperature at..." sounds like a remark  than a title.

Comment: I have never heard of such arbitrary capitalisation. If you are referring to title casing, fine; but then you should capitalise everything.

Comment: Noted your point. Title-cased the main words.